# Block the user request from URL

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, servlet-filters

I need to implement a logic in my project to block the user request from the URL bar, let say user is in middle of one module and user wants to resubmit / refresh the page, in normal web applications user can Go to URL bar press enter. But in my project we need to block the user to send the request from URL bar and redirect the page to Page / Session Expired page .
I think we can achieve this by using a servlet filter by checking the request , whether the request is coming from URL bar or a form. Is there any way to check where the request is coming from ?

Answer (score 0):

Use any Random Token Number generated with URL request and every time validate the token.

Comment: i think it is not the best way to validate the token in each and every request, it is like duplicating the same logic in each and every screen to send the token and validate the token and reset the token. instead of doing this, we can write a filter to check the request .

Comment: But you need at least one parameter associated with each request to validate in filter or anywhere else. I don't think there is any difference in request coming from a form or a URL Bar other than the parameters.

Comment: yes, there is no difference between request is coming from form or a URL bar. but is there any way identify the request, whether user had submitted the form by pressing enter in the URL bar.

Comment: I don't think that will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply authentication filter to restrict access to other pages,if user try access the unwanted page make him land on your desired  page.